# How do I interpret spaces in python byte arrays

Tags: python

I am receiving some data from a third party and stumbled over a curious feature of the byte array output:

Some byte arrays I receive have spaces in the string which is printed to console, and I do not know how to interpet these.

```py
a = b'\x14 \x00'
b = b'\x14\x00'

print(len(a), ':', a[0], a[1], a[2])
print(len(b), ':', b[0], b[1])
```

results in the output

```
3 : 20 32 0
2 : 20 0
```

Where does the 32 (which is '\x20' in hex) come from?
ASCII space is 32, but why is this interpreted as such?

Comment: Those are actually `bytes` objects, not `bytearray` objects, but that's just being pedantic. In any case, I'm not really sure I understand your confusion. You seem to be aware that it represents byte 32. Have you consulted the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects)?

Comment: I guess the space (0x20) is just printed out as such

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for the quick response. I guess I was confused as to why it chose to display ASCII, while i was expecting just hex values

Comment: Try `>>> bytes(range(256))` to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[32 is the decimal value](http://www.asciitable.com) for the string " " (a space). In Python, a [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects) object is an iterable of bytes 0-255, which can be represented by `\x14` for 0x14, or ASCII characters like `a`, `b`, or `c`. Or a combination of the two, as you've seen in your example.

```
list(b'\x01\b02')   # [1, 2]
list(b'ab')         # [97, 98] (decimal values for 'a' and 'b')
list(b'\x12ab\x44') # [18, 97, 98, 68]
```

Comment: so python will display the ASCII char unless there doesnt exist one?

Comment: @SchillerFalke2 From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects): "Only ASCII characters are permitted in bytes literals (regardless of the declared source code encoding). Any binary values over 127 must be entered into bytes literals using the appropriate escape sequence."